# Using simple foreach loop instead of foreach with key=>value in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have written this code with Yii2 a long time ago to fetch photos for a slideshow and then choose another image size among several images and although it works, as I haven't been working with PHP recently, I don't understand why. I think I should be able to use a simple foreach loop, but when I change it to a simple one, it doesn't work.
This is the code:

```
public static function getSlideShowPage($type)
{
    $slideShow=SlideShow::find()
        ->select(['title','image','title_position','subtitle', 'title_color'])
        ->where(['deleted' => 0,'active'=>1,'type'=>$type])
        ->orderBy('id ASC')
        ->groupBy('id')
        ->asArray()
        ->all();
    if(!empty($slideShow))
    foreach ($slideShow as $key=>$slide){
        $slideShow[$key]['image']=str_replace('_xs', "", $slide['image']);
    }
    return $slideShow;
}
```

and what I'm having a problem with is this part:

```
    if(!empty($slideShow))
    foreach ($slideShow as $key=>$slide){
        $slideShow[$key]['image']=str_replace('_xs', "", $slide['image']);
    }
```

Why can't I write it like this:

```
if(!empty($slideShow))
    foreach ($slideShow as $slide){
        str_replace('_xs', "", $slide['image']);
    }
```

In each foreach loop, I choose one of the array elements and replace the URL of the image.
I would appreciate any help or suggestion.

Comment: Pass it by reference and assign it back? `foreach ($slideShow as &$slide) { $slide['image'] = str_replace('_xs', "", $slide['image']); }`

Comment: @Qirel I did that too, it wont work. In my opinion they are doing the same thing, so I cant figure out why that works and this doesn't. :/

Comment: @Wiz Are you sure you didn't forget `&`? That code is basic pass-by-reference and does work, so you must be missing something.

Comment: @Jeto Uh thanks for bringing it to my attention! It's working now!

Comment: @Qirel Thanks a lot for helping me out! It's working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Qirel mentioned you should pass it as reference but also you have to do something with the result of str_replace:

```
foreach ($slideShow as &$slide){
    $slide['image'] = str_replace('_xs', '', $slide['image']);
}
```

Comment: If you're doing this though, you should also do `unset($slide)` after the loop for safety, or you're gonna have a bad surprise if you happen to make use of `$slide` later in the script.